# Sigasi in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, vhdl, sigasi-studio

I have just installed the Sigasi Studio pluginin Eclipse (version: Eclipse IDE 2018-12). When I try to launch it,to make a new VHDL file, I get the following:

> The selected wizard could not be started. org/eclipse/lsp4j/Range
>   (occurred in com.sigasi.hdt.vhdl.ui.VhdlExecutableExtensionFactory)
>   org/eclipse/lsp4j/Range

How I could solve it, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's only part of the error, can you have a look at the log file (Help > Open log)? You can always just email directly to Sigasi (support@sigasi.com) for these kind of question.

As for an actual solution, it sounds like something went wrong during the install of the plugin, can you try reinstalling the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIGASI + GHDL + GTKWAVE (all in one)

It is very powerful combo that you can set up. ATTENTION i use macOS 10.13.6:

**Step 1**

Make sure you have both installed GHDL and GTKWAVE typing

```
$ which gtkwave
/usr/local/bin/gtkwave
$ which ghdl
/usr/local/bin/ghdl
```

**Step 2**

Open Sigasi an make new Project and create an additional compile.sh file with:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROJECT_NAME="PWM_Generator"
PROJECT_NAME_TB="PWM_Generator_tb"
WORKING_DIR="/Users/imeksbank/Dropbox/UMHDL"

/usr/local/bin/ghdl -a --workdir=$WORKING_DIR/work.ghdl $WORKING_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME.vhd;
/usr/local/bin/ghdl -a --workdir=$WORKING_DIR/work.ghdl $WORKING_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME_TB.vhd;
/usr/local/bin/ghdl -e --workdir=$WORKING_DIR/work.ghdl $PROJECT_NAME_TB;
/usr/local/bin/ghdl -r --workdir=$WORKING_DIR/work.ghdl $PROJECT_NAME_TB --vcd=$WORKING_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/simulation.vcd;
```

now, be aware, for each project you create your own variables like

- *PROJECT_NAME*
- *PROJECT_NAME_TB*
- *WORKING_DIR*

I use always Dropbox for such approach because then i can access via Windows as well.
And of course, there is a possibility to create custom variables in *Sigasi ->  External Tool Configurator -> Program -> compile_sh -> environment* to pass them to make *compile.sh* independent. Here you have to deal with it by yourself =)

**Step 3** .

Set up you *External Tools Configurations* to let shell script be executed by Sigasi Studio and create the **.vcd** file for **gtkwave**:

Click on currently created Project (in my case it is the PWM_Generator).
After that click on *Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations ...*.
Then go to the left sidebar and under *Program* create your own anchor like *compile_sh*.

Finally you have your route :

- Program
- --compile_sh

And now extend this anchor by a custom created shell script :

*Main->Location* gets *${workspace_loc:/PWM_Generator/compile.sh}*
*Main->Working Directory* gets *${workspace_loc:/PWM_Generator}*

Click Apply and Run and that's it !!! After this you can program VHDL / Verilog and compile via *Run -> External Tools -> compile_sh* having created **.vcd**. In your project appears the gtkwave file and there just double click and it starts. =)

Comment: UPD : another useful thing is, just add " --wave=simu.ghw" at the end after the "simulation.vcd" . The GHDL generates the .ghw simulation as well since you can't see you STATES in case of FSM in VCD.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Sigasi support, I was able to solve the problem. They wrote me:

> The lsp4j plugin version is to recent for the xtext version that ships
>   with Sigasi Studio 4.2. This issue has been resolved in the preview
>   channel of release 4.3. Therefore - if you wish to use the plugin
>   version of Sigasi Studio - I recommend to install the 4.3 preview
>   following the steps explained on
>   http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/preview.html.

That's all. Now, I would like to configure Sigasi with GHDL (as a compiler, when I run the project) and GTKWAVE (ad a waves viewer). How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.